# Google Places API in Android - API_KEY for individual users

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have gone through the Android documentation and other blogs related to using the Places API in an Android application. Everywhere it suggests to use the API_KEY to call the REST service. The API_KEY being the same throughout the project/application. There is a limitation of 1000 requests per day.

Now if my application is installed by many users, then the request limit will be easily exhausted if the same key is used by everyone.

There would be some way to generate the API_KEY for individual user. But how can I take care of it in my code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can have the quota raised to 100,000 requests a day if you verify your identity:

> Users who have verified their identity through the APIs console are
>   allowed 100 000 requests per 24 hour period. A credit card is required
>   for verification, by enabling billing in the console. We ask for your
>   credit card purely to validate your identity. Your card will not be
>   charged for use of the Places API.

You'll find this information and more if you go to the Google APIs Console, select *Services* and click on the *Pricing* link on the *Places API* line.

100,000 requests a day is a lot and should be sufficient unless your app is extremely popular.  And I don't think that creating several user to generate several API keys will be possible without violating Google's terms and policies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Codo! Though I'm still working on the app, I don't mind being positive about its popularity :) On a serious note, I have seen many popular apps which shows the places around you. So I am guessing they all use the Places API. Just wondering how it works in their case?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they use a single API key. Some of them might have their quota lifted above 100,000 requests a day. A [separate page](https://developers.google.com/places/uplift) describes how to request it.