# Google geocoder Vs places API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using Geocoder - getFromLocationName to return address list based on a search string. This works well.

I came across the Places autocomplete API recently and I am thinking will it be a better idea to use Places autocomplete instead of Geocoder. I mean what will be the difference between using these two. From both I can get locations and display using a marker. So will it be neater to use Places autocomplete? The only disadvantage I can see the quota limit placed on the Places autocomplete api whereas there is none on using Geocoder.
Can someone throw some light on it please?

Answer (score 2):

For your concern you can use both of them ..

**Disadvantage of using Geocoder**: In some devices Geocoder method does not return device coordinates

**Disadvantage of user Places API** : Quota limit.

So as to accomplish your task .. you can make use of both stuff like this ..

Firstly make use of Geocoder method and check for it's returned value ..

If Geocoder method return value is not Null then use that coordinate else if it's returned value is Null then make use of Places API.

Hope it clears your doubts .. I personally use this way.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Please check out this .. [Google Places API in Android - API_KEY for individual users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786465/google-places-api-in-android-api-key-for-individual-users)

Comment: well, it could be tricky to use both incase you are showing the results as the user types in the search box

Comment: Oh yeah .. you have to do like this as First one do not provide result in all devices and other have Quota limit. So as to ensure reliability of application you have opt this work around. :)